# I lost 100 reputation and it is not shown in graph

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-graph, offensive

Last December I lost 100 reputations on Music Stack Exchange as one of my answers were marked as "rude or abusive" by 6 users.  However, the graph did not lose 100 reputations.  What's the reason?[image]

Comment: No bug. As the answer on the dupe says: "Those carry 100-point rep penalties, and such penalties are hidden from the public".

Comment: Ah, I see.  Good answer!